# Set today date to Default Value or Binding

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, getdate

I'm using MSSQL2008.  The date type is `Date`, and I would like to set the default date to now or today.

I've tried `GETDATE()`, but I get "Error validating the default for column 'Date'". If I persist with `GETDATE()`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GETDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) returns a [`DATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) that you can subsequently [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to the [`DATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type:

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: I does work, actually CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) gets transformed to CONVERT([date],getdate(),0). I don`t think the 0 is relevant because I convert the date value to string. Now, when I create a textbox the default value is still 01 Jan 0001.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that you are setting `Date` in the correct place? according to your error message it looks like the column name is `Date`, not the type; make sure the type is Date and try again, `GETDATE()` as a default should work fine

Comment: The table atribute is Data and the data type is date.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
```